# UL LI Navigation Menu, Extra spacing?

Tags: css, wordpress

I can not for the life of me figure out why the spacing is not even across the first navigation menu on my site:

http://www.eureporter.co/

I have set the widths correctly, but on both 'Citizen Journalism' and 'Photo Journalism' appear to have extra padding either side of them, I just want them all the be even!

Can anyone help?

Comment: change width to `159px` at this line `#main-navbar ul li a` `style.css Line # 7260`

Comment: Won't work without !important

Comment: Don't forget to make your header and footers `min-width: 960px;`

Comment: Thank You! Is there any way to spread them all out evenly? So the same concept is applied and same spacing etc.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `display: table-cell; width: auto;`, which makes each `<li>` using width relative to it's content.

Use

```
#main-navbar ul li a { 
    width: 159px !important;
}
```

To make them all equal width.

Comment: Thank You! Is there any way to spread them all out evenly? So the same concept is applied and same spacing etc.

Answer (score 0):

actually, to make even cells in a `<table>` or tags displayed as `table-cell;` , you only need to give a small value like : `width:1%;`. It will stretch evenly each 'cells' to fill the entire width of parent `<table>` or **displayed** as `table`.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FegoG (resize window's width to see what happens. you can copy/paste rules value for cells wher you need it : ) )